# How to model a Facebook like Friends list using Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, entity-framework

I'm designing a new website using MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5 also I am using the Model-First to design my database.
I have a User entity and I want it to have a list of friends of the same type (User).
I want to use a Facebook like scenario where users request friendship and when the request is accepted, they will become friends.
I guess I should make a self-referencing many to many connection between user and itself but I don't know there to keep the requests and how to handle the rejection or acceptance of the requests to add the user to the list!
Sorry if it got complicated, I really tried to keep it simple but couldn't do any better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a seperate entity(s) to store these connections.  That way you can add fields to tell who initiated and when, and when it was accepted/rejected/blocked, or after an amount of time you ignore and allow another friending attempt; might only allow 100 friend requests at a time, etc.  Might move to another entity after friendship established.  You may also want to consider how you will be counting the number of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. order of friends - ends up this calculation can eat your lunch if done in real-time (I think that is what killed Friendster back in the day).  Good luck!

```
Users
- Id
- Name

FriendRequests
- UserId
- FutureFriendId
- Message
- TimeStamp
- ApproveFlag
- RejectFlag
- BlockFlag
- SpamFlag
- ExpiresDate

Friends
- UserId
- FriendId
- FriendType
- FriendHasThisManyFriends
- TheirFriendsHaveThisManyFriends
- WhenWeBecameFriendsDate
```

Probably a million ways to set this up.  No claim this is the best.  Just have fun with it!  Enjoy.

Comment: I had thought about a similar solution but the problem is that I can't really figure out what the relation between the User and Friend must be, a Many to Many or a One to Many. A user can have many Friends and also a Friend can have many friends but because of the fact that a Friend is not a real User that should be a one to many relation (I guess) but what happens to the opposite relation? When a User has a Friend the Opposite user should have the User as a Friend too. Should I add the user to the friends' friend list manually? Was the question clear?

Comment: All your choice.  Manually moving the friendship from the request state to both directions (meaning twice) in the Friends is what I was thinking.  By manually, I mean a procedure or stored procedure.  So each of the two new friends gets a record including how many friends their new friend has - which is calculated in background process.  Then the math to know how many friends-of-friends I have is trivial.  Again I caution on this aspect. :-)